# Subassembly structure of DFMEA

Tags: circuit-design

I am working on a DFMEA for a PCBA and have broken it into 3 areas, System, Sub-Assembly (Circuits) and Sub Assembly Characteristics.

The System and Characteristics were easy to put together but I am struggling with the Sub-Assembly and how to integrate Electrical functions and Mechanical functions.  Should I outline the mechanical properties (package size, placement on PCB) as its own "sub-assembly" to list the functions of not interfering with surrounding environment (moving parts near PCBA) or include them in each sub-assembly with the electrical functions?

I am only responsible for the PCBA DFMEA, it has to fit into an Assembly with a customer who is doing their own DFMEA on it.